# List Newbie : List of xml element and Domain objects are overwitten with each iteration

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I have two Domain classes as follows:

```
Class FooA:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XXX.MyCore.Domain
{
  public class FooA
    {
        public string String_FA { get; set; } 
        public string String_FB { get; set; }

    }
}

Class FooB

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XXX.MyCore.Domain
{
    public class FooB
    {
        public string FooC{ get; set; }
        public List<FooA> FooA_List { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My xml has repeated nodes as follows (6 total):

```
:
:
      <ns2:Example>
        <A>DataA1</A>
        <B>DataB1</B>   
      </ns2:Example>
      <ns2:Example>
        <A>DataA2</A>
        <B>DataB2</B>
      </ns2:Example>
:
:
```

I have another class which references these domain objects.

```
:
:

List<FooA> fooANodeElemValue = new List<FooA>();
FooA fA = new FooA();

// I now iterate through the XML elements to parse sibling values

 foreach (XElement elem in document.Descendants().Elements(nsUsr + "ExampleA"))
                                {
                                    fA.String_FA= elem.Element("A").Value;
                                    fA.String_FB= elem.Element("B").Value;


                                    fooNodeElemValue.Add(fA);
                                    FooB.FooA_List= fooNodeElemValue;

                                }
```

I am able to build a list of six parent items and the respective sub- elements each containing the fA objects. However,with each iteration in the forEach block, the list is overwritten with the new sibling node values. 
Specifically,

```
fooNodeElemValue.Add(fA);
```

and

```
FooB.FooA_List= fooNodeElemValue;
```

are overwritten.

Thus when the loop is complete, each list element is replicated 6x
So,

```
FooB.FooA_List[0] = {DataA2, DataB2}
```

and

```
FooB.FooA_List[1] = {DataA2, DataB2}
              :
              :
```

Any help is tremendously appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to instantiate a new FooA in each itteration. Secondly, there is no reason to reset the list each time, you can use the existing one. Try these changes:

```
// Create a new list and assign it to the public property of FooB...
FooB.FooA_List = new List<FooA>();

foreach (XElement elem in document.Descendants().Elements(nsUsr + "ExampleA"))
{
    // Create a temporary variable (in the scope of this loop iteration) to store my new FooA class instance...
    FooA fA = new FooA() { 
        String_FA = elem.Element("A").Value, 
        String_FB = elem.Element("B").Value
    };

    // Because FooB.FooA_List is the list I want to add items to, I just access the public property directly.
    FooB.FooA_List.Add(fA);
}
```

Doing things like creating a whole new list and then assigning that list to the property of `FooA` is just a lot of extra work. `fA` is an instance that exists only within the scope of the *current loop itteration*, as soon as the loop goes to the next one, `fA` is automatically brand new, as though it never existed.

`FooB.FooA_List` is *the list instance* you are adding things to. It doesn't make sense to constantly reassign this variable to a different copy of your list instance. So, there is no need to use `FooB.FooA_List = whatever` within your loop since you can access the instance directly via `FooB.FooA_List`, and make it do your work via `FooB.FooA_List.Add(whatever);`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out prior to reviewing your response. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue is.
1. I need to instantiate the fA object within the loop.
2. I need to set the fA object to null within the loop.

```
foreach (XElement elem in document.Descendants().Elements(nsUsr + "ExampleA"))
{
FooA fA = new FooA();                             
fA.String_FA= elem.Element("A").Value;
fA.String_FB= elem.Element("B").Value;

fooNodeElemValue.Add(fA);
FooB.FooA_List= fooNodeElemValue;
fA =null;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to set it to null at the end of the loop. As soon as a single loop itteration completes, all scope variables, of which fA is one, are descoped. Also, you don't need to set `FooB.FooA_List = ` anything every time in the loop. It's already been set once, you can now just reference it and update it through `FooB.FooA_List.Add(fA);` Your code is more confusing than it needs to be. I'll update my answer with comments that better explains it.